# What's the difference between International and US configuration (on Amazon)?

Tags: equipment-recommendation

I'm referring to what's listed on Amazon under the configuration. Here's an example: [https://www.amazon.com/Tamron-28-75mm-Aspherical-Digital-A09NII/dp/B001955P8W/ref=sr_1_4?s=photo&ie=UTF8&qid=1473506919&sr=1-4&keywords=tamaron](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001955P8W)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"US Version" lenses are imported into the US by the official distributor. They come with a US warranty.

"International Version" (also called "gray market") lenses have been (legally) imported into the US by a third-party. But since these lenses were not intended to be imported into the US by the manufacturer, they come with a different warranty, which may or may not be valid in the US. In case the warranty is not valid, sometimes the third-party importer will offer a third-party warranty instead.

In either case, the lens itself is the same.

Addendum: I just noticed that Amazon explains this themselves right on the page:

> This [International] version is originally intended for sale outside the US and may contain adapters, manuals, and warranties not compatible with US standards.

Comment: The Amazon statement also suggests that the manuals might not be compatible with US standards — which probably means the page of warnings everyone skips over might not match what's supposed to be there. And "adapters" might mean power cords for battery chargers — but I can't think of anything else. Can you?

Comment: The manual may also be written in a language different than English, particularly in the version of Chinese used in Hong Kong which is where a lot of gray market electronics originates.